# Does maintaing the Directory Structure Matter when exporting/importing Subversion Dump Files?

Tags: svn

Working on ripping and replacing an old RHEL5 VM that hosts a Subversion repository.

I plan on generating dumps of each repo and then will import the dumps into the new RHEL7 VM running Subversion.

My question is, will I have to have the same type of directory structure on the RHEL7 VM that I have on the RHEL5 VM?

For example:  current Subversion repo exists as under `/data/svn/DeptA/ProjectA`

I would like to make the directory names lower case, to make it easier to type, such as:  `/data/svn/dept_a/project_a`

As long as I use the `svnadmin` create command against the `/data/svn/dept_a/project_a`, I wouldn't think there would be an issue.

Comment: The dump of the repository does only contain the changes for each revision but no information about the repository itself (by default). For more information you should read these chapter http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.8/svn.reposadmin.maint.html#svn.reposadmin.maint.migrate

Comment: One thing you might consider is, that the UUID of the repository will change and for your repository users it seems like a new repository. To avoid this take a look at the last section in the chapter linked above.

Comment: Thanks for the help, I have that pdf copy of red-bean and will reference it.  Just a lot to go thru when learning this.